# Make an outline with GIMP, like in Photoshop

Tags: gimp

How do I add a stroke to a layer in GIMP?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Per the GIMP documentation *Edit > [Stroke Selection](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-selection-stroke.html)*:

> The Stroke Selection command strokes a selection in the image. There are two ways you can stroke the selection, either by using a paint tool or without using one. This means that the selection border, which is emphasized in the image with a dotted line, can be drawn with a stroke. There are various options which you can use to specify how this stroke should look.

#### Instructions

1. Create a new Layer [image]
2. Make a Selection via *Rectangle Select Tool*  [image]

   [image]
3. Go to *Edit > Stroke Selection* and setup your desired *Line width*:

   [image]

**Note:** The stroke color is been taken from the current *Foreground color*.

#### Result

[image]

Comment: For hours on end I've been trying to add a border around a half elliptical pasted selection, and I can see that it has the dotted lines, so it is selected, but for the life of me I cannot put a border around just this selected half elliptical.